# Add custom property to serialized object

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm developing RESTful API for a web service. And I need to expose some properties that do not belong to an entity itself.

For example I have a `Pizza` entity object, it has it's own `size` and `name` properties. I'm outputting it in JSON format with *FOSRestBundle* and *JMSSerializer*. I've setup properties annotations for this entity to expose needed properties via serialization groups and it's working great.

But I need to add some properties that do not belong to the entity itself. For example I want my `pizza` to have property: `isFresh` that is determined by some `PizzaService::isFresh(Pizza $pizza)` service. How do I do this?

- Should I inject some additional logic to serialization process (if so how)?
- Should I create a wrapper entity with properties that I want to expose from original entity plus additional *external* properties?
- Should I add property `isFresh` to the original `Pizza` entity and populate in in the controller before serialization?
- Should I return additional data independent of entity data (in a sibling JSON properties for example)?

In other words: what are the best practices around this issue? Could you provide examples? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to create my own class to serialize an entity.

Here's the example:

```
class PizzaSerializer implements ObjectSerializerInterface
{
    /** @var PizzaService */
    protected $pizzaService;

    /**
     * @param PizzaService $pizzaService
     */
    public function __construct(PizzaService $pizzaService)
    {
        $this->pizzaService = $pizzaService;
    }

    /**
     * @param Pizza $pizza
     * @return array
     */
    public function serialize(Pizza $pizza)
    {
        return [
            'id'      => $pizza->getId(),
            'size'    => $pizza->getSize(),
            'name'    => $pizza->getName(),
            'isFresh' => $this->pizzaService->isFresh($pizza),
        ];
    }
}
```

You just have to configure DC to inject `PizzaService` into the object serializer and then just call it like this from the controller:

```
$pizza = getPizzaFromSomewhere();

$pizzaSerializer = $this->get('serializer.pizza');

return $pizzaSerializer->serialize($pizza);
```

The object serializer will return an array that can be easily converted to *JSON*, *XML*, *YAML* or any other format by using real serializer like `JMS Serializer`. `FOSRestBundle` will do this automatically if you configured it so.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do that with the VirtualProperty annotation :

```
/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isFresh (){
     ...
}
```

Edit : another solution with the Accessor annotation

```
/** @Accessor(getter="getIsFresh",setter="setIsFresh") */
private $isFresh;

// ...
public function getIsFresh()
{
    return $this->isFresh;
}

public function setIsFresh($isFresh)
{
    $this->isFresh= $isFresh;
}
```

In your controller, you call the setIsFresh method

(See http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotation)

Comment: This question is also about this virtual property being dependent on a service, seems like this is only a part of the answer. Maybe you can suppose a way to implement that too?

Comment: Yes, you have right. I think "Should I add property isFresh to the original Pizza entity and populate in in the controller before serialization?" is the better solution. For this, i add another way with the Accessor annotation

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Why do you think this approach is better? What are the drawback of other approaches? Have you implemented this design in practice?