# Is it allowed to compute properties of an object for its representation?

Tags: rest, many-to-many, data-representation

I am facing the following situation:

I have a `Post` object, that is linked via a many-to-many relationship to a `Comment`object. a `Post`can have a maximum of 2 `Comment`s marked as "Top".

I need to expose an API providing the function of listing Posts (aswell as showing a detailed view of a Post, but this one is okay). The problem is, that a `Post` can have a huge amount of `Comment`s, and I don't see myself displaying this representation:

```
[{
   title: "Lorem ipsum",
   ....
   comments: [{
          "author": "...",
          "comment": ".....",
          "top": false
         }, ... // repeat a few thousand times
   ]
},...
]
```

However, I know that a majority of consumers of this API will later want to display directly the top comment(s), so I am thinking of exposing this representation:

```
[{
   title: "Lorem ipsum",
   ....
   topComments: [{
          "author": "...",
          "comment": ".....",
         }, .... // repeat once more if needed
   ]
},...
]
```

Here I choose not to display all the comments, which could be accessed through /posts/ID_OF_POST/comments, however I compute at "runtime" a `topComments` property (which is not in the original Object in the code), and display the comments marked as top

Is it allowed to compute using business logic and expose a property that doesn't exist in the object represented ? What if, later, I would like to add a new `numberOfComments` computed property, would it still be okay ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Yes it's allowed, it's named "transient" or "virtual" properties.

Comment: @See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926254/add-custom-property-to-serialized-object

Comment: @MathieuDormeval can you post this as an answer ? I would be very happy to accept it as it has perfectly answered what I want ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's allowed, it's named "**transient**" or "**virtual**" properties.

With Symfony Framework, you can do that like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926254/add-custom-property-to-serialized-object).

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it allowed to compute using business logic

Of course it is.

> and expose a property that doesn't exist in the object represented?

I would not return different *representations* but use a different *resource* to get the collection resource of top comments.

```
GET /posts/{postId}/top-comments
```

would return an array of comments in the same form as in the complete list, but only the top comments would be included.

You can also use a filter on the original collection:

```
GET /posts/{postId}/comments?top=true
```

Comment: But since the array of top comments is quite small (2 objects maximum), can I include it directly in the representation of the Post list ?